# Can I reload trustmanager after opening serversocket in a ssl connection

Tags: java, sockets, ssl, serversocket, sslcontext

Lets say I have created a SSLContext, created a serverSocket from the serverSocketFactory and I have started accepting connections.

something like:
`SSLContext.getDefault().getServerSocketFactory().createServerSocket(1234).accept();`

Assume it is running for sometime and now I decide to modify my TrustManager(add/delete new certificates to trust). Is it possible to do this without closing the socket and creating a new SSLContext?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reloading a java.net.http.HttpClient's SSLContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69506869/reloading-a-java-net-http-httpclients-sslcontext)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following approach.

First, you keep a reference to your `SSLContext` object when you are creating it.

```
SSLContext sslContext=SSLContext.getDefault();
sslContext.getServerSocketFactory().createServerSocket(1234).accept();
```

Then, when you want to load the new `TrustManager`, you can call the `init()` method again with the corresponding **TrustManager** as follows.

```
TrustManager trustManagers[] = // load trust managers here.
sslContext.init(null,trustManagers,null);
```

Here, the `init()` method takes 3 parameters, `KeyManager[]`,`TrustManager[]` and `SecureRandom`. If you pass `null` for any of them, the `SSLContext` will be loaded with the default Key Managers and Trust Managers. Since you want to load the Trust Managers only, you have to pass the new `TrustManager[]` to it.

Since you are not changing the reference to your `SSLContext` object, this will not break your flow or will not affect your existing `SSLIOSession`s.